# mbBgndGallery - jquery gallery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello and thanks for reading.

Currently I am working on a project that has "mbBgndGallery" as a gallery plugin for background animation.

It works perfectly with images but I need to load text as well.

This is URL of plugin and the solution author provides to use text:
http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-bgndgallery/comment-page-6/#comments

Actually I a really close to resolving it but for now I have following init:

```
if(slider_options.fx == 'zoom')

            {
var caption=["11111111",
"22222222",
"33333333",
"444444444",
"55555555555"
];

                //BG SLIDESHOW WITH ZOOM EFFECT
                $.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery({
                    containment:"body",
                    timer:14000,
                    effTimer:14000,
                    controls:false, //updated in v1.1
                    grayScale:false,
                    shuffle:false,
                    preserveWidth:false,
                    preserveTop: true,
                    effect: slider_options.fx,
                    //effect:{enter:{transform:"scale("+(1+ Math.random()*2)+")",opacity:0},exit:{transform:"scale("+(Math.random()*2)+")",opacity:0}},

                    // If your server allow directory listing you can use:
                    // (however this doesn't work locally on your computer)

                    folderPath:false,

                    // else:

                     images: slider_options.slides,

                    onStart:function(){},
                    onPause:function(){},
                    onPlay:function(opt){},
                    onChange:function(idx){
if(caption[idx])
$("#desc").fadeOut(function(){$("#desc").html(caption[idx]).fadeIn()});
else
$("#desc").fadeOut();
},
                    onNext:function(opt){},
                    onPrev:function(opt){}
                });
            }
```

Images do rotate properly but the div I need to load content just fade out -

```
#desc
```

May be someone will notice the stuff I am missing - just do not know how to deal with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just `hide/show` caption rather that animating it via `fadeIn/fadeOut`, check code below:

```
onChange:function(opt,idx){
    if(caption[idx]) {
        $("#desc").html(caption[idx]);
    } else {
        $("#desc").html("");
    }
},
```

Reason behind it is that internally slideshow is running with some timer events and once you try to call function `fadeIn/fadeOut` other timer events are bind and they do not remain in sync  with original slideshow timer events.

PS: You will also need to add a blank div with id desc and style it using css.
i.e. `<div id="desc" style="font-size: 20px; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid red;"></div>`

Comment: Thank you VERY much! You saved me a bunch of time